# Scaling the target variable is giving error in Python using StandardScaler of Sklearn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Scaling the target variable by normal procedure of using StandardScaler class is giving error. However, the error got resolved by adding a line `y = y.reshape(-1,1)`. After which applying the fit_transform method on target variable gave the standardized value. I am not able to figure out how adding `y.reshape(-1,1)` made it work?

X is independent variable having one feature and y is the numerical target variable 'Salary'. I was trying to apply Support Vector Regression to the problem, which needs explicit feature scaling. I tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()

X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

It gave me error like:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead Reshape your data
>   either using `array.reshape(-1, 1)` if your data has a single feature
>   or `array.reshape(1, -1)` if it contains a single sample.

After I made the following changes:

```
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

The standardization worked just fine. I need to understand how adding this `y = y.reshape(-1,1)` helped achieve it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes up a lot in SKLearn. 
From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) of the scaler's `.transform` function, the input to `.transform` has to be a 2D matrix where the second dimension is the number of features:

> Perform standardization by centering and scaling
>
> Parameters:    X : array-like, shape [n_samples, n_features] The data
>   used to scale along the features axis.

Now, the last dimension has to be explicitly set to 1, not missing. Before the data is reshaped (i.e. `y=y.reshape(-1,1)`), the last dimension is missing - see this example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,0])
print(a) # [0 0 0]
print(a.shape) # (3,)
b = a.reshape(-1,1)
print(b) # [[0] [0] [0]]
print(b.shape) # (3,1)
```

The [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method changes the shape of an array: for example, if a is an array with 6 elements (and whatever shape), `a.reshape(3,2)` changes its shape to 3-by-2. 
The -1 argument basically means "use the dimension that is needed here so that the data fits".
 So, `a.reshape(-1,1)` an array with n elements to an n-by-1 2d array (without explicitly specifying n).

Comment: So, will it be correct to say that StandardScaler class needs a matrix rather than a vector to perform standardization?

Comment: Do you understand how `reshape` works, and what does -1 mean? If not, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: It would be better for everyone, if you could just add it to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, Added it.

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes you would need to transform it. This is because as per the sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform), `fit_transform` expects the `X` or predictor variables to consist of `n_samples` with `n_features`, which is make sense to what it used for. Supplying only 1-D array, this function will read it as 1 sample of `n_feature`. Perhaps attaching the code below will make this clearer:

```
In [1]: x_arr                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[1]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) # will be considered as 1 sample of 5 feature

In [2]: x_arr.reshape(-1,1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: 
array([[1], # 1st sample
       [2], # 2nd sample
       [3], # 3rd sample
       [4], # 4th sample
       [5]])# 5th sample
```

Anyway, on how you use the `StandardScaler` (unrelated to your question on why your code produce error, which answered above), what you want to do is using the same `StandardScaler` throughout your data. Generally speaking, scaling the target variable isn't necessary since it's the variable you'd like to predict, not the predictor (assuming `y` in your code is the target variable).

First, you'd like to store the mean and standard deviation of your training data to be used later in for scaling the test data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

# Here the scaler will learn the mean and std of train data
x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train, y_train)

# Use here to transform test data
# This ensures both the train and test data are in the same scale
x_test_scaled = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

Hope this helps!